# How to find page by uid in TYPO3 BackEnd

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 the fileadmin tells me a file I want to delete is used on two pages. It lists the ids but gives no link or other information to identify the page. Since my site has thousands of pages, I don't want to hover over each page link to see the id and find the right one. So:

How can I call up the page in the backend if I have the id?

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using ?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply search by pid (page id) using either the filter above the page tree:

[image]

or the search box on top right:

[image]

Both will return the page with that pid.

Btw: it is a good idea to display the pid in the pagetree. There's a TSConfig setting for that, but it can be done easily by using the extension tsconf.

Comment: In TSconfig in backend user set `options {
  pageTree.showPageIdWithTitle = 1
}`

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the number in the Ref column, you get a popup (see the screenshot : http://s22.postimg.org/480t2hk69/tmp.png). Table, is the table in the database which using your file, and uid, is the uid of the record using your file. So if a refer to the screenshot,  it tells me that my file is used in the table tt_content, uid=318, in the field bodytext. So it's in the page content 318. Then you can simply make a search in the TYPO3 backend

Comment: Searching for the uid numbers returns no results, in my case.

Comment: Maybe the're hidden or deleted. Try to search in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: What did you search for in the backend? Have you tried "tt_content:xyz" (where xyz is the uid)?